# when upload larger file, getting this error:Error 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net, web-config

We are getting error when trying to upload a large size video file to our admin site.
We are able to upload small size file without a problem, this error start happening when file size more then 10Mb, where as we already increase size by following configuration setting in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="2400" maxRequestLength="102400"  useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true" />
```

and Error message is when we upload larger file:

```
Error 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: Can you post the code that throws the error?  You can [edit] it into your existing question.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

o finally got the right solution for this issue, we need add requestFiltering under security in web configuration, following are the code i added in web.config and its start allowing me to upload larger file:

```
<security>
       <requestFiltering>
               <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
       </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits "Specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in bytes. The default value is 30000000, which is approximately 28.6MB."

Comment: Where in web.config is this placed in? `<configuration>`? `<system.webServer>`?

Comment: @JackCole based on the link in the comment above, yes

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in the web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxxxx" />
  </system.web>
```

`"xxx" is in KB`. And the default is `4096`, Which is equals to `4MB`.

Comment: this is also needed (note that this is in KB), but doesn't return the 404 error if missing (see the other answer on requestFiltering - which btw needs value in bytes)